# What's the easiest way to check nuget package platforms?

Tags: nuget

I know name of nuget package in official nuget gallery. How can I check on which platforms it's avaibale, e.g full .net, silverlight, windows store apps, universal platform, etc..?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows I normally use the [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/) which will download the NuGet package and show you its contents. The frameworks it supports are shown in the lib directory inside the NuGet package.

You can also just download the NuGet package from NuGet and unzip it.